# How to setup redis-server 3.0.7 for Tyk 1.9.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, redis, tyk

I get the following error when trying to start my redis instance using tyk:

```
ERRO[0000] Could not EXPIRE key: could not complete command
ERRO[0005] Multi command failed: could not complete command
```

I did set the following parameters :

```
port 6379 - cluster-enabled yes - cluster-config-file nodes.conf - cluster-node-timeout 5000 - appendonly yes
```

I've also tried to set maxmemory-policy to any parameter but it doesn't change anything.

Anyone who has already configured redis-server with cluster mode for Tyk?

Running Redis server v=3.0.7 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and Tyk v1.9

Answer (score 0):

There is a documentation for setting up [redis clusters](https://tyk.io/docs/tyk-stack/tyk-gateway/configuration/redis-cluster/) now for recent versions.